# How to count the total number of items in Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, printing, web-scraping

So I written a program to scrape a site for items in a Reg Ex statement, email, phone number and images. Bare in mind ive not long just started learning python.

the code that I'm using to scrape the site is:

```
def main():
    url = "URL in here!"
    webpage = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    content = webpage.read()
    f = open('CSN08115-TestPage.txt', 'w')
    f.write(content)
    f.close()
    print content
    print GetLink()

def GetLink():
    with open('CSN08115-TestPage.txt') as f: 
        for line in f: 
            c = re.findall(r'a\shref="/?(.*)">', line)
            #Code to find total number of Lines of c
            if c:
                print c, 'Total number of emails: 6' #Output should adjust to different websites

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

**My question is how do I count the total number of outputs from the RegEx statement**

I've tried using `print c, len(c)` but this only outputs a 1 next to each output! There is a total of 6 emails. My thought behind this is that c = re.findall creates a list for each email found in c, in turn giving the result of 1 per each email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the input I can't be positive, but I suspect you ought to call re.findall on the entire page content instead of on one line at a time:

```
   ...
   content = webpage.read()
   ...
   c = re.findall(r'a\shref="/?(.*)">', content)
   number_of_items = len(c)
```

Comment: So what you suggested works! but not it outputs into a horrible list.

How would I output it goes top to bottom of the list?

Comment: @Scott, you just sort the list out or make it a dict.